# Add target=_blank to outside links

Tags: php, regex

I want to add `target="_blank"` to `<a>` tags to open that link in a new page, so I found this RegEx :

```
$content = preg_replace('/(<a href[^<>]+)>/is', '\\1 target="_blank">', $content);
```

This will work without any problem, but this code will add `target="_blank"` to all links, I want to add just to links which `href` will start with `http://`

How can I do this?

Comment: just add "=http\://" to your regex after "href"

Comment: @DanieleD Thanks, I use your solution, but in `//` I have error: https://regex101.com/r/bV6dE8/1

Comment: forgot to escape the slashes: =http\:\/\/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(<a\b[^<>]*href=['"]?http[^<>]+)>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wD1uW6/2).

I have added `\b[^<>]*` to account for any other attributes before `href`.

Sample code:

```
$re = "/(<a\\b[^<>]*href=['\"]?http[^<>]+)>/is"; 
$str = "<a href=\"do.com\">\n<a href=\"do.com\">\n<a another=\"val\" href=\"http://do.com\">\n"; 
$subst = "$1 target=\"_blank\">"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score 3):

You've asked for a regular expression here, but it's not the right [**tool**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // Load your HTML

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "http://")]');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

If you want to exclude internal links as suggested in the comments, you can do:

```
$links = $xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@href, "http://") and 
                        not(starts-with(@href, "http://yoursite.com")) and
                        not(starts-with(@href, "http://www.yoursite.com))]');
```

Comment: There is a problem in this solution. Sometimes internal links may be linked through `http://mysite.kom/the-link-path` or `http://www.mysite.kom/the-link-path` so how could we add the `or` to the regarded Xpath? i.e `http://mysite.kom` and `http://www.mysite.kom` to exclude them from being targeted to `_blank`.

Comment: Very good, Thank you, I suggest to add this comment to the answer. @hwnd